# Is the argument of zero tangential field components in wave guide walls a fallacy? Or: How EM waves "magically" find their correct transverse modes

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, microwaves, waveguide, normal-modes

I just came across a nice answer on Quora, [explaining visually](https://qr.ae/prwpLG) how wave guide modes can be constructed from the condition of *zero tangential fields in the wave guide walls*.

In mathematical terms, this corresponds to a certain set of boundary conditions for the Maxwell equations resulting in a certain set of [solutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_mode). The physical reasoning is that for perfectly conductive walls, any non-zero tangential fields would induce infinite currents in them - therefore, the waves somehow *"know"* which modes to choose and which to avoid, or, as the author of the cited answer writes,

*"One nice thing about the wave guide is that you don’t have to design the waves. You just stick an antenna in the wave guide and **the field just finds the correct angle** for each wave train. **The waves simply propagate in a mode that they can**."*

Obviously, it wasn't the author's intent to personify waves as sentient beings who test out different modes and select only those consistent with physical laws. Still, both the mathematical as well as physical arguments kind of put the cart before the horse:

1. The boundary conditions are not axiomatically derived, but a *conscious choice* made by whoever sets up a theoretical calculation or simulation. They do not *follow* from the differential equations, but are *chosen* as parameters (correct me if I'm wrong).
2. Similarly, the physical argument against infinite currents inside the wave guide walls is a *justification*, but not an explanation of fundamental causes or underlying physical processes.

The question is therefore:

What is the **real** physical mechanism behind the emergence of distinct propagation modes inside wave guides? What rather than who decides in which modes waves can propagate and in which they cannot?

- Could it be that the "zero tangential fields" argument is factually wrong?

Meaning: If we (quote) *"stick an antenna in the wave guide*", could it be that there are indeed high-frequency currents induced inside the walls - or rather: in the wall [surfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skin_effect) - such that any modal components, whose tangential fields don't perfectly cancel out, simply **dissipate as heat** (resistive/absorptive loss) or **leak out** (radiative loss)?

Note that wave guides are in general fabricated from either highly conductive materials (usually metals) or have at least a highly conductive inner layer/coating (copper or even gold), both of which actually *facilitates* an effective induction of currents!*

A definite answer from someone with either experimental (e.g. RF/microwave research) or theoretical experience (e.g. FDTD simulation) would be much appreciated.

---

*Addendum: The choice of material actually depends on the frequency of the electromagnetic radiation and doesn't necessarily have to be a metal, but can be anything that is *sufficiently conductive* at the desired frequencies.

Comment: The waveguide actually is in charge of the waves and tells them whose allowed where. Seriously though, the boundary conditions (ie waveguide geometry) of your PDE's, here Maxwells equations determine this. The boundary condition says there's an equipotential along the inner metallic wall of the waveguide (ie zero E-field)

Comment: supported modes interfere constructively (for the most part)

Comment: @R.Rankin Hi, thanks for your comment! Concerning the equipotential, then why can't you just use any material (e.g. wood or plastic) for wave guides? Also, isn't the equipotential (approximately) realized precisely due to currents or, in the case of dielectrics, a polarization of the wall material? Which, in the case of RF frequencies, would result in energy dissipation

Comment: @antimony You mean this is a purely "optical" effect of waves reflecting from the walls?

Comment: simple guided mode phenomena can be shown purely from interfering and reflecting waves. incorporating polarization or full EM will give a much more complete answer of course.

Comment: for the equipotential the material needs to be conductive, which leads to reflection, and antimony's comment. Wood doesn't hardly restrict E-Fields therein, but a conductive material spreads charge out equally throughout the whole wall. try reading about TM, TE, and TEM modes for for detail on this.

Comment: @antimony So you basically agree that the "zero tangential field" argument is either factually wrong or at least unnecessary/misleading? If not, how does a purely "optical" construction of wave guide modes from reflecting and interfering waves require vanishing tangential fields? The reflection of EM waves from an optical mirror doesn't require it, right?

Comment: @R.Rankin *All* materials exhibit both reflection and transmission to a certain extent. That includes metals, but also materials such as wood. However, the "zero tangential field" argument requires *vanishing* fields along the wave guide surfaces, i.e. either waves propagating exactly tangentially or a superposition of waves such that the tangential field components cancel out (as visualized in the [cited Quora article](https://qr.ae/prwpLG)). If you look up TM/TE/TEM modes, Fresnel equations etc., you'll see that in general we do **not** have vanishing tangential field components!

Comment: @antimony ...actually, have a look at [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations) and [interface conditions for EM fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_conditions_for_electromagnetic_fields): They require a *continuity* of tangential field components across interfaces, not *vanishing* fields! I'm feeling increasingly suspicious about this whole "zero tangential field" argument

Comment: @sarahslvmn    sure there are frequency dependent skin depths electric field penetrations in a conductive wall. This really becomes the purview of "plasmonics".  Yes waves reflect, transmit and refract through most anything, but the definition of waveguide incorporates a material that can guide the waves, where reflection dominates, mostly necessitating a good conductor (or total internal reflection for light). Also, note that that there is technically a discontinuity in the normal E-field component, but this is highly dynamic and nonlinear when you look at charge dstbns on those time scales

Comment: I once came across a paper having calculations for  a gravitationally self confined laser beam, but I wouldn't call it a waveguide, just some wild nonlinear phenomena.

Comment: @R.Rankin So I dare to say that we agree on having a certain amount of "guidance" with different materials, even in the case of wood or other non-conductive materials (only the efficiency will be very low). But the problem is more fundamental: IMHO the whole argument of vanishing currents along wave guide surfaces is **wrong** or at least missing some important bit of explanation

Comment: @R.Rankin Let's not stray to far from the topic... ;)  But yes, one can imagine closed path of light also under purely graviational influence. Circular light rays on the Schwarzschild radius of a black hole, I think, would be a prominent example. And one, indeed, where you can have both zero tangential field components (when the light is polarized along the orbital plane) or maximal tangential field components (when the light is polarized perpendicular to the orbital plane).

Comment: Yes, ultimately zero tangental is technically the *electrostatic* approximation, because the relaxation time is so quick, we often use it in dynamics as well

Comment: @sarahslvmn    Find a copy of Jacksons Classical Electrodynamics 3rd edition if you have access. section 8.1 (4 pages) will answer all of your questions. (I was just thumbing through mine, it's been a while Was my book for a fun filled year long grad class ). It specifically goes through the failure of the tangental E field and normal B-field to vanish in a waveguide.

Comment: The reflection actually happens over a depth in the conductor. you could think of it as jumping on a trampoline, the wave pushes into the metal, but ultimately the metal (charge distribution) catches up and pushes it back out. Now that I'm thinking about it, passive radars are designed to detect even people moving around by our reflections of (now ambient) waves like cell signals.

Comment: @R.Rankin Thanks for the reference, I'll check it!

Answer (score 1):

> You wrote: "stick an antenna in the wave guide", could it be that there are indeed high-frequency currents induced inside the walls - or rather: in the wall surfaces - such that any modal components, whose tangential fields don't perfectly cancel out, simply dissipate as heat (resistive/absorptive loss) or leak out (radiative loss)?

In a "normal", ie., copper or plated copper waveguide of high wall conductivities the dissipation is insignificant for your question. What is significant, however, is that all those non-propagating but excited modes, say in a fundamental mode guide, form a reactive field around launcher and increase its reflectivity back to the generator. In other words, you have a generator connected, for example, to a coaxial line whose outer sheath is soldered to the top wall of rectangular waveguide and its inner conductor is inserted as a wave launcher, antenna probe, inside the guide otherwise insulated from everything else.

Assume that the generator's source impedance $Z_s$ is equal to the wave impedance  $R_w$ of the coaxial line: $Z_s=R_w$ and thus if the coax is terminated at its other end with a load impedance $Z_L$ such that $Z_L=R_w$ the there is no reflected wave propagating on it in either direction. Now connect the waveguide whose one end, the far end from the probe, is also terminated with a perfect absorber designed so that is matched for modes in the waveguide, in practice it could be a tapered longish resistive cone or pentahedron structure attached to the end wall. So in the direction towards its load the waveguide is well-matched.

But inserting the probe you notice that depending on what you to do at its near end of the waveguide the reflectivity in the coax changes. Usually the simplest thing to do is to have a movable metal "piston" placed about a quarter wavelength (measured in the waveguide $\lambda_g$) away from the probe. The round trip reflection from the probe towards this back wall will be a about a half wavelength, so would come back essentially in the opposite phase but there is also a phase flip on the shorted back wall, so instead of canceling reflected wave it as actually an "electrical" open circuit (ie.,no load) on the probe. Now by adjusting the short wall's distance relative to the probe with the probe's depth it is possible to eliminate all reflections going toward generator from the probe on the coaxial line. In other words, if the magnetic field is stronger around probe than its electric field, that is if the probe is "inductive", than we we add a little capacitance, electric energy, in parallel to it.

The actual distance where this happens depends on the probe's depth in the waveguide but it is roughly around a quarter wavelength as measured in the guide, ie., in terms of propagating mode wavelength.

Now, what does this really mean? It means that $\ell_s \approx \lambda_g/4$ at which the probe is matched, that is when the movable short has length $\ell_s$. Then there is no reflection measured in the coaxial line towards the generator from the probe, and essentially all energy from the generator is transferred to the waveguide in its propagating mode going toward the far end matched load. Every discontinuity in a homogeneous transmission line/waveguide will excite an infinity of modes, some propagating, some localized, but they are there. By properly adjusting the depth of the launcher together with the length of movable short we will have prevented those excited waves to be launched back to towards the generator and "focused" them be coherent with the propagating mode directed towards the load. There is still EM reactive energy staying around the probe, just there would in an LC filter in its passband, but their only observable effect at a *single* frequency is to shift the phase of the incident wave from the generator as it passes through it. By properly adjusting the depth of the probe with the back short distance one can eliminate all reflections. It matters what the actual depth of the probe/back short distance if you care to operate at a wider frequency band along the radius and detailed shape of the probe becomes important, etc. Some combinations are better than others, and as you can imagine there is a science associated with designing the probe, especially the shape of the tip for higher powers, etc.

Comment: Incredible description! re. "non-propagating but excited modes" is there a name for these modes? Thanks!

Comment: @antinomy evanescent modes

Comment: Thanks! So the presence of these reactive fields around the launcher indicate imperfect impedance match of the launcher? Since if it coupled 100% power into the fundamental mode that would be a perfect impedance match. But since it also couples some power into non-propagating modes, the impedance match by definition is not 100%? Consequently the input(?) impedance of the launcher has changed?

Comment: Which in turn leads to some power being coupled into backwards propagating modes, which propagate back towards the generator?

Comment: That is correct. Around a discontinuity all the modes of the waveguide will be launched by some amplitude and phase. Usually waveguides operate at a frequency so that only  a single mode can propagate, and the other modes have "imaginary" wavelengths, thus exponentially decay. They represent a reactive load and oscillating energy in the sense of  a lumped element component in a circuit, L and C. The effective impedance of the launcher and the waveguide following is the result form the reactive energy stored in the evanescent modes and the wave impedance of the propagating mode down the guide.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I need some time to digest this

Comment: Hi, I've tried to picture your experimental setup, but it's not easy to understand your description (partly, because the grammar is a bit mangled here and there). Could you please add maybe a simple sketch or do a quick cleanup of your text? I'm considering it an acceptable answer once it's clear. Thanks a lot

Comment: Example: *"Now by adjusting the short wall's distance relative to the probe with the probe's depth it is possible to eliminate all reflections going toward generator from the probe on the coaxial line."* - What are you adjusting, this "movable metal piston", the insertion depth of the exposed coax core antenna, both? And how exactly does this affect reflections towards the generator?

Comment: Worse, the following sentence, which appears to be an important conclusion from the one above, is entirely incomprehensible: *" In other words, if the magnetic field is stronger around probe than its electric field, that is if the probe is "inductive", than we we add a little capacitance, electric energy, in parallel to it."*

Comment: I do have a physics background, but **absolutely** no idea what you are trying to convey here. There are some waveguide/antenna geometries, some movable walls, phase shifts, reflection, and - boom - suddenly some magnetic fields which are stronger around a probe than some electric fields, then some induction happening, a little pinch of capacitance here, a little pinch of electric energy there, and everything somehow "parallel" to something... My point is: Even with an illustration, this wall of text would be really difficult to understand (unless maybe for someone...

Comment: ...who already has thousands of hours of experience in RF/microwave engineering and just "sees" everything you describe immediately by verbal association)

Comment: @antimony If you completely understood hyportnex's answer, you can also edit it or add a sketch in order to improve it (if you want)

Comment: Also this sentence: *" Every discontinuity in a homogeneous transmission line/waveguide will excite an infinity of modes [...]"* - What is "discontinuity" referring to? I thought the coax cable, waveguide etc. are all continuous? And what kind of discontinuity are we talking about, refractive index/conductivity/permittivity/permeability...? And how/why do discontinuities "excite an infinity of modes", is this some mathematical concept?

Comment: @srhslvmn it will be difficult to answer this torrent of questions in comments, and this  stackexchange forum discourages to do so. I suggest that you ask them in separate formal questions and I will be happy to try to answer them to  the best of my ability. In the mean time you may wish to consult a standard textbook on the subject, e.g., https://archive.org/details/principlesofmicr0000mont

Comment: @hyportnex Respectfully disagree. Nobody expects answers to get accepted with zero request for clarification, especially if the answer does indeed lack clarity or even has grammatical errors that make parts of it incomprehensible. That is, we have a minimal quality standard here. Take, for instance, just this sentence: *"In other words, if the magnetic field is stronger around probe than its electric field, that is if the probe is "inductive", than we we add a little capacitance, electric energy, in parallel to it."*

Comment: PS.: Thanks for the link

Comment: You may ignore my questions regarding the impedance matching using the movable piston (I've looked this one up), but you seriously need to clean up your answer a bit and also clarify on the quoted sentence. Better yet, you just add a very simple, rough sketch that shows all the variables in the text

Comment: @hyportnex Also, this sentence is **factually wrong**: *"Every discontinuity in a homogeneous transmission line/waveguide will excite an infinity of modes"* - Consider a planar boundary (a "discontinuity") between two homogeneous media with different refractive indices (e.g. an ideal air/water interface) through which electromagnetic waves from a point source propagate. Depending on the refractive indices and polarization, a certain part of the wave energy is reflected, the other transmitted through the boundary surface (Fresnel formulas). ...

Comment: ... But the incoming, reflected, and outgoing waves are all spherical. There is no *"infinity of modes"* being excited at all. You can also add conductive walls across the boundary to form a wave guide - again: No *"infinity of modes"*, just a free-space solution and a wave guide solution. And in case your wavelength is longer than the lowest supported wave guide mode, you only get the free-space solution and zero propagation inside the wave guide (except maybe evanescent fields around the entrance).

Comment: Factually speaking, the Fresnel formulas do not hold for spherical waves.

Comment: @hyportnex Thanks for your response. Could you briefly explain? Is this a geometric problem (e.g. related to wavefront curvature) or are you referring to the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem#Physical_exemplifications) and the non-existence of actual spherical EM waves? Also, are you by any chance referring not to discontinuities in the wave guide, but perhaps rather *discontinuities in the 1st derivative of a waveform* (which can only be constructed from an infinite number of Fourier components)?

Comment: The so-called Fresnel formulas are about an infinite plane wave hitting an infinite  plane dielectric surface, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations. The transmitted, reflected and refracted plane waves do solve Maxwell's equation and at the refracting boundary they together satisfy the continuity boundary conditions. When applied to an incident spherical wave they can only do so approximately and only locally in the sense that  it be over short distances of the wavefront relative to its radius of curvature, i.e, a locally plane wave approximation.

Comment: A *homogeneous* (metallic) waveguide is a homogeneous structure in one of its dimensions, say $z$, but it can be inhomogeneously filled in its $x$ and $y$ directions, If in the $x,y$ dimension it is finitely bounded with ideal metal (zero resistivity) and it is also completely homogeneously filled then the solution of the corresponding Maxwell's equation between prescribed boundary conditions can be represented as the linear combination of a discrete set of basic solutions, so called modes.  A discontinuity is *anything* that disrupts the homogeneity in the $z$ dimension.

Comment: The Fresnel equations are very much local in that they describe reflection and transmission at each point of a boundary. The plane waves are only a mathematical construct - they're unphysical - and represent "building blocks" from which you can construct arbitrary wave fields (plane wave decomposition), such as the spherical ones frequently encountered in imaging optics. In practice, most if not all sources are approximately spherical (atomic emission dipoles), from which one gets approximately planar wavefronts in the far field, e.g. from an "array" of planar surface emitters (Huygens ...

Comment: ... principle) or astronomical objects

Comment: I have no experience with RF wave guides, but have worked with optical fibers. Maybe the underlying principles (e.g. for coupling into RF wave guides and fibers) are similar. With fibers, you need to focus light onto the facet of the fiber core with a numerical aperture smaller than a certain value (or you'll lose efficiency) and there is also a cut-off wavelength, above which the fiber acts as a single-mode fiber and below which as a few-/multi-mode one. Maybe RF wave guides behave in an analogous way?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane-wave_expansion